# Saga not getting called on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

I have this saga-reducer-store code that should in theory fire a saga event on `dispatch`, but I see that no action happens at all. This code does work on react.

A related SO question is [Redux saga - Worker saga not getting called on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472960/redux-saga-worker-saga-not-getting-called-on-react-native) but the solution is outdated as `take*` form `redux-saga` is deprecated.

Code below -

- App.js calls configureStore() that returns store and runs the saga
  middleware.
- Store calls the rootSaga.js that returns all the sagas there are.
- rootSaga.js calls loginSaga.js (userLogin) Saga

rootSaga.js

```
import { takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";
export function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(LoginSagaConstants.LOGIN, userLogin)
}
```

loginSaga.js

```
export function* userLogin(action) {
   console.log("userLogin not getting called");
   const response = yield call(LoginAPI.login, action.user);
   console.log(response);
   ...
}
```

loginScreen.js

```
console.log("start dispatching");
dispatch({
    type: sagaConstants.LOGIN,
    user: {
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        robottest : "robottest"
    }
});
```

store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
const initialState = {};

// import all Reducers
import {reducers} from "./reducers";

// import all Sagas
import { rootSaga } from "./sagas";

// define middlewares
let middlewares = [];

// create and add the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
middlewares.push(sagaMiddleware);

//add the freeze and logger dev middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middlewares.push(createLogger());
}

// apply the middleware
let middleware = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

const enhancer = compose(
    middleware
)

export default function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer);
    // run saga middleware
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    return store;
}
```

App.js

```
...
import configureStore from './store'
const store = configureStore();
...
render() {
     return (
         <Provider store={store}>
             <RootStack/>
         </Provider>
    );
}
```

my console only prints `start dispatching` and nothing else happens.

Comment: Can you add your `sagas/index.js`?

Comment: let me add explanation of the code, just a min

Comment: @PritishVaidya please check the description, the sagas/index.js as you asked should be loginSaga.js

Comment: You also need to post your reducers, it would be great if you could make a snack expo [here](https://snack.expo.io) or provide us with a sample git repo to work on.

Comment: @PritishVaidya i think I found the issue, I am using react-navigation and RootStack is a react-navigation element, and it is not passing down the dispatch or store :/ now I am trying to figure out a simple solution

Comment: Either you can access the `store` directly or use `redux helper functions` such as `connect()` to bind your component to a store aware `HOC`

Comment: accessing the store does seem to work. thanks